# Debugging re-compilation of wil6210 driver for LEDE v17.01.2

Tags: debugging, driver, openwrt, wifi, recompile

I want to modify wilocity wil6210 driver, recompile it, get .ko file and use it on a system running LEDE v17.01.2

I successfully recompiled the driver but when I try integrating the module into the kernel using modprobe I get `module could not be probe`

Anyone has ideas about how to debug this issue ?

Regards,

Mohammed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second paragraph as you mentioned below:
I successfully recompiled the driver but when I try **integrating** the module into the kernel using modprobe I get

`module could not be probe`

Here are you really integrating or inserting above module into the kernel?

I believe for wil6210 module, there are other dependency modules are there
1. `cfg80211`
2. `compact`
you need to insert those modules first, then insert the wil6210 module, it would resolve your issue